# C code: cannot print out the whole linked list as I expected

Tags: c, data-structures

I've been staring at those code for so long and it still doesn't work as I expected it to. The code should just enable the user to initialize a linked list by entering the length of it and the data of every node, and it prints out all the data afterwards.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;

int n,x,i;
Node* head = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));

void Init(int x, Node* temp){
    Node* newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = newNode;
    temp = newNode;
}

void Print(){
    Node* temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main(){
    printf("Please enter the number of nodes in the linked list：\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    Node* temp = head;
    printf("Please enter the data of the node：\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d", &x);
        Init(x,temp);
    }
    Print();
}
```

I think maybe there's some problem with the `head` node. As I run the code, the data seems to be inserted without a problem but it cannot print out everything from the very beginning from the `Print()` function.

This is what it looks like when I run it.

```
Please enter the number of nodes in the linked list：
4
Please enter the data of the node：
1
2
3
4
4 -842150451 Press any key to continue
```

I guess I may have missed something very basic here, sorry if I have since I'm new to learning C and data structure.

Comment: Rather than just staring at the code, I suggest firing up the debugger and stepping through it to see what happens. As you examine the values of each variable, you will quickly see where the problems arise when something unexpected happens.

Comment: Also it might be more appropriate to change the name of `Init()` to `Add()` or `Insert()` since this more clearly describes what the function does.

Comment: You also need to be more careful about how you create the first node in the list.

Comment: If this compiles, you must be using a C++ compiler (which would explain the casts on the result of `malloc()`).  You have an external variable definition `Node* head = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));` which is simply not valid in (standard) C — you can't use a function call to initialize a global variable in C (but you can in C++).  Your variables `int n, x, i;` should be local to `main()`.

Comment: You should check the calls to `scanf()` and `malloc()`.  There's no need to make the user specify how many numbers they're going to enter; use: `while (scanf("%d", &x) == 1) Init(x, temp);` (or the fixed-up version of that function call, using whatever fixup is appropriate).  This iterates until the user gets bored and indicates EOF (typically control-D on Unix or control-Z on Windows), or makes a mistake and types a non-numeric character (a comma, perhaps).

Answer (score 1):

There is problem with your `Init` function, you need to add the new node at the end of the linked list.

Try the fixed code:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;

void Init(int x, Node* head)
{
    Node *temp;
    //Add the new node to end of the list
    for(temp=head;temp->next!=NULL;temp=temp->next); 
    Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(!newNode)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of mem\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = newNode;
    temp = newNode;
}

void Print(Node* head)
{
    Node* temp = head;
    while(temp->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int clean_stdin()
{
    while (getchar()!='\n');
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int n,x,i;
    int c;
    Node *head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(!head)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of mem\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    head->data = 0;
    head->next = NULL;

    printf("Please enter the number of nodes in the linked list: ");
    while(scanf("%d",&n) != 1)
    {
        printf("Please enter the number of nodes in the linked list(Integer value): ");
        while(getchar() != '\n');
    }
    //Clear input buffer
    while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF );

    printf("Please enter the data of the node：\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        while(scanf("%d", &x) != 1)
        {
            printf("Please input an integer\n");
            while(getchar() != '\n');
        }
        //Clear input buffer
        while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF );
        Init(x,head);
    }
    Print(head);
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: `int n,x,i;` should be in `main()`.  You don't initialize the data that `head` points to; it is pure chance that it points to zeroed memory.  If I initialize it (`head->data = -37; head->next = (Node *)0xDECAFBAD;`) then the program crashes.  You should not depend on chance to make your program work.  You should check the memory allocations too.  The line `Node *temp = head;` in `main()` defines an unused variable — my compiler tells me as much (because I told it to tell me about silly mistakes).  You should check the result of `scanf()` too.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler, now onward I'll compile the code with `-Wall -Wextra -Wshadow` option. Updated the code with all your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This function

```
void Init(int x, Node* temp){
    Node* newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = newNode;
    temp = newNode;
}
```

doesn't change the `Node` in the calling function. Not only that, `newNode` is now a memory leak.

Your code needs a bit of re-working. `Init()` can be designed to add items at the end of the list or at the start of the list. You have to decide which behavior you want to implement. After that, `Init` needs to be reworked a bit to match the expected behavior.